# if else not returning expected output inside async function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await

**Nodejs sample code:**

```
try {
  const nonIssueDay = await NonIssueDay
    .aggregate([{
      '$match': {
        '$or': [{
          'noIssueDate': date
        }, {
          'noIssueDate': tomorrowDate
        }]
      }
    }])
  if (nonIssueDay.noIssueDate !== tomorrowDate && nonIssueDay.noIssueDate !== date) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'order will proceed as usual'
    })
  } else if (nonIssueDay.noIssueDate === tomorrowDate) //tomorrowDate:2020-02-07T18:30:00.000Z
  {
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'holiday'
    })
  } else if (nonIssueDay.noIssueDate === date) //date:2020-01-31T18:30:00.000Z
  {
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'd-14 will displayed'
    })
  }
} catch (error) {
  res.send(error);
}
```

**Mongodb collection:**

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e3bedd96cfe9912ece7772e"),
    "date" : "07.02.2020",
    "city" : "Chennai",
    "state" : "Tamil Nadu",
    "noIssueDate" : ISODate("2020-02-07T18:30:00Z"),
```

**POSTMAN RESPONSE :**  `{"message": "order will proceed as usual"}`
i need to check all the conditions and accordingly my queries will run but no matter what checks i place it gives the same response which is mentioned in the "postman response", how to meet all these conditions

Comment: Both of these are true: `nonIssueDay.noIssueDate !== tomorrowDate` `nonIssueDay.noIssueDate !== date` have you console logged all those vars to see if one is coming up undefined or something?

Comment: What's the type of `date` and `tomorrowDate`? You need to pass in `Date` objects, not strings, in case you're doing that.

Comment: @anna i had consoled console.log(nonIssueDay) that's working but when i consoled..console.log(nonIssueDay.noIssueDate) this is undefined and i kind of knew that but whats the work around then to meet these conditions

Comment: @– technophyle dont worry about the date objects they are working as expected i already have defined that, to avoid confusion i also have mentioned the date & tomorrowDate console result in my question "nonIssueDay query is working "( if & else if) statements are not working.. can you suggest anything what might be wrong

Comment: The work around is to find out where noIssueDate is supposed to be defined and why it isn't coming through for you. `undefined` will always `!== someValue` so you will need to find the circumstances where it *will* fail that check and you're comparing the things you want to. You will need to have a look at your nonIssueDate. Is it the object you expected or is it an array?